# С чего начать?

Tags: jquery, html, php, javascript, mysql

В целом, вопрос адресован белорусам. Уважаемые подскажите с чего начать и главное где? Заканчиваю БНТУ по специальности web-разработка, имеются средние знания html/css, чуть хуже js/jq, php/mysql, большой минус слабое знание английского. Опыта нету, особенно командно разработки. В идеале, хотелось бы работать над проектом от макета до сдачи(кроме самого дизайна). Неплохо было бы и программистом JS или(и) PHP. В общем поделитесь как кто начинал и посоветуйте что рабiць )))

Comment: Не знаю как-там у вас, но общие соображения подсказывают что начинать придётся либо джуниором работающим за еду, либо фрилансером (работающим за еду).

Английский учи, всяко пригодится. Читай стэковерфлоу и доки по используемым документам. Английски это тебе не китайский или русский, язык простой в общем-то.

Так-же полезно подучить и другие ЯПы (python, ruby, может даже какой-то clojure), как минимум рля расширения кругозора, что-бы таки стать программистом, а не дрессированной мартышкой. Опять-же PHP кодеров на рынке до чёрту, конкуренция высока.

Это всё так, общие соображения.

Comment: тебя же по направлению в какую нить контору засунут, вот в ней и работай, правда в них общий уровень компетенции очень маленький. вообще не понятно зачем для веб вышка.

Comment: Скооперируйся с одногрупниками и сделайте web-студию.

Comment: > вообще не понятно зачем для веб вышка

@eicto, Ну, как же? Направление сегодня популярное? Да. Деньгу платить студенты будут? Куда ж денутся. Дык, почему ж на этом не заработать? А то, что они после окончания будут иметь: "*средние знания html/css, чуть хуже js/jq, php/mysql*", да еще и английский на уровне "Hello, world!", но только со словарём - так это их не **е**[*цензура*]**т**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

советую идти в крупную компанию типа Epam, Itransition и т.п. они почти всегда набирают джуниоров. работа не сахар, придется повкалывать пару лет за копейки, но зато наберетесь опыта. это лучше, чем фриланс, т.к доход хоть и не большой, но стабильный. фрилансить можно пробовать параллельно. дальше, как правило, люди из таких компаний уходят либо в более мелкие на аутсорсинг, либо открывают что-то своё. разберётесь. с опытом, если станете нормальным спецом, вариантов будет намного больше.
так же не советую идти на позицию html/css разработчика, т.к в среднем ЗП намного ниже, чем на позиции PHP/Mysql. но конечно же, нужно выбирать то, что больше по душе.
удачи